# How to render a List in playframework

Tags: java, list, playframework-2.0

i am wondering how i can render a List to template as an ajax callback arg.

i did this:

```
List<String> filteredTW = Twitt.filtertw(tagname);
return ok(filteredTW).as("text/plain");
```

but is says, i need to define ok(List) function on my own. is it true that Playframework doesnot offer this function?

i would be thanksful to any attemp to help..

EDIT: my ajax function is:

```
    $(function() {
    $('.filter').click(function() {
        var tagname = $(this).text();
    $('.post').remove();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/filter',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            context: this,
            data: { tags: tagname },
        }).success(function(response) {
            alert(response);
        });
    });
})
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try `return ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(filteredTW));`

In this case, you can treat `response` as a regular javascript array.

```
for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
  alert(response[i]);
```

Comment: oh okay.. honestly, i never used json before, how can i then catch this json for my success function in ajax?

Comment: are you using something like jquery? it should come back as a javascript array.

Comment: SUPER! learnt new thing :)). Thanks man, you are great! it is working.

Comment: You can also prefer to use the jquery function $.each to iterate an array.  $.each(response,function(i,res){ alert(res); }); //where response is an array.